# I need assistance with Powershell if/then syntax

Tags: if-statement, syntax, powershell-2.0

We have a library of 3500 documents for which we're building metadata. About 1/3 of the documents have `BC` in the title and I want to flag these. Right now, here's what I have and it works fine:

```
$htmPath = "c:\ht"
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $htmPath -filter "*.htm*"
ForEach ($doc in $srcfiles)
{
    $s = $doc.Fullname
    if($s.contains("BC")) { $bcflag = 1 } else {$bcflag = 0}
    Write-Host "File: " $doc.Fullname "  BC Flag: " $bcflag
}
```

It's just come to my attention that there may be some documents with `bc` in the title, so I need to add an `OR` to my condition test. I've been unsuccessful with the word `OR`...errors out with bad method calls, `|` as a symbol for or...thinks I'm trying to pipe something, and for some reason, I can't include a regex. I can get it to work if I add a duplicate `if` statement with `bc` as a condition, but there has to be a way to provide a list of options rather than a series of statements each looking for a single value.

What is the proper syntax to

a.) Provide a list of conditions to test and/or

b.) use a regex in the above statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The or operator in Powershell is -or so you probably want

```
if($s.contains("BC") -or $s.contains("bc")) { $bcflag = 1 } else {$bcflag = 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

using regex:

```
if($s -match 'bc')
```

or just

```
if($doc.fullname -match 'bc')
```

default `regex` isn't case-sensitive, the will match "BC" or "bc".